# Renaming convolution tag to conv-neural-network, or creating a new conv-neural-network tag

Tags: discussion, tags

How about renaming the [convolution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convolution) tag to [conv-neural-network](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/conv-neural-network/synonyms), or creating a new `[conv-neural-network]` or `[cnn]` tag?

Most questions tagged with convolution are about CNNs.

Comment: Quite a few posts tagged convolution are not about CNNs, too, so I don't think we should simply rename the tag. Whatever we do I'd prefer if we could end up with a convolution tag that was actually for, you know, convolution.

Comment: @Glen_b sounds good

Comment: +1 for raising this issue, but I agree with @Glen_b that we should not rename it. Looks the tag should be split instead. Ideally somebody needs to go through all the questions in [convolution] and manually retag the ones that are about CNN.

Comment: By the way, there is around 25 questions mentioning "convolutional neural network" [with convolution tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22convolutional+neural+network%22+is%3Aquestion+[convolution]&tab=votes) and around the same number [without this tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22convolutional+neural+network%22+is%3Aquestion+-[convolution]&tab=votes). You might want to go through the latter category too and see if there are threads worthy of adding the new tag to them.

Comment: @amoeba good catch, thanks, I'll look at it.

Comment: I accidentally noticed that there is still over 20 questions about CNNs with convolution tag, some of them well upvoted, [see here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22convolutional+neural+network%22+is%3Aquestion+%5Bconvolution%5D&tab=votes). Would be great if you could retag those, I actually thought you already did it last year :-)

Comment: @amoeba I may have forgotten to complete it, since Stack Exchange doesn't provide any good way to retag many questions at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [convolution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convolution) tag currently has no excerpt or full wiki.

I would say the first thing is to create those.  In particular, the excerpt should (briefly) provide a clear understanding of what convolution *is* (i.e., it isn't a convolutional neural network), and explicitly state that the tag should NOT be used for CNNs.

Then we should create a [conv-neural-network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conv-neural-network) tag (and possibly a `[cnn]` tag made immediately into a synonym).  Subsequently, there will have to be a process of re-tagging those threads that are actually about CNNs.  It is best to do that 3-4 threads at a time, and when traffic on the site is slower.

Comment: "The convolution tag currently has no excerpt or full wiki." -> done.   "we should create a [conv-neural-network] tag" -> done. Can you mark it as synonym for cnn? thanks

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, I cannot--I am not a moderator. I cannot even suggest it as a synonym, b/c I don't have 5 upvotes on the tag (that system doesn't work anyway). It might be better to hold off on these actions to build more of a consensus from the community first, though.

Comment: +1. @Franck, for the time being I still think it's better to manually retag cnn->conv-neural-network, and continue retagging convolution into conv-neural-network. And please write an excerpt for conv-neural-network too!

Comment: @amoeba " please write an excerpt for conv-neural-network too! " -> done

Answer (score 1):

I created a [cnn](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnn) tag, and started retagging.

Comment: +1, but is this abbreviation recognizable enough? I think [conv-neural-network] could be better (and it's probably still not too late to change).

Comment: @amoeba Sure we can always rename the tag or create a synonym anytime. No preference.

Comment: Experience tells that it's *much* easier to create a good tag name from the beginning, then to rename it later. Tag renamings and synonyms tend to be difficult to initiate here. I think if somebody writes a question about convolutional nets, they will start typing "convolutional..." in the tag field and will likely never find [cnn]. I suggest we switch to something that begins at least with "conv".

Comment: @amoeba sounds good, let's wait to see whether people are ok with [conv-neural-network] then retag accordingly. I've never really understood how tags work.

Comment: @aamoeba  done. Seriously there is no mod tool to do it?

Comment: There is a tool, but our mods are (for reasons not totally clear to me) rather reluctant to carry out tag merges/renames, even the trivial ones. E.g. there are currently over 10 pending suggestions on meta for over a month. Perhaps the tool is complicated to use.